# posting iterated data in one request with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5.1

i am currently developing a simple examination application using angular as my frontend and i have encountered this problem which is bugging me for two days till now, my problem is how to make a request(POST) in which your data to be post is comming from a iterated data (in my case, is question.id and tempanswer (ng-repeat directive)) in my view, i know how to post single request but not on this-- ^_^.

take a look on my snnipet code..

Backend.

```
public function submitExam() {

    $student_id = $this->request->student_id;
    $subject = Subject::find($this->request->subject_id);

    //$question_count = Question::where('subject_slug', $subject->slug)->count();

    $tempAnswers = json_decode($this->request->answers);
    //dd($this->request->answers);
    foreach ($tempAnswers as $tempQuestionKey => $tempAnswer) {

        Tempanswer::insert([
            'question_id' => $tempQuestionKey,
            'temp_answer' => $tempAnswer,
            'student_id'  => $student_id,
            'subject_id'  => $subject->id
            ]);

        Examinationresult::insert([
            'question_id' => $tempQuestionKey,
            'subject_id'  => $subject->id,
            'student_id'  => $student_id
            ]);
    }
```

Angular(frontend).

```
$scope.mobileSubmitExam = function() {
        var result = $window.confirm('Are you sure to submit?');
        //var tempAnswer = {$scope.examDetail[0].id: $scope.answers};
        var submitInfo = {
            'answers': $scope.answers;
            'student_id': $scope.studentDetail.id,
            'subject_slug': $scope.subject_slug,
            'subject_id': subject_id
        };

        if(result == true) {

            $http.post(BASE_URL + 'mobile/examination/submit', submitInfo)
                .success(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .error(function() {
                    $window.confirm('Error on submitting the examination!');
                })
        }
    };
```

View(Html).

```
<div ng-show="!examKey" class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div class="card card grey darken-3">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
                <div>
                    <header>
                        <small>
                            <strong>
                                <p>Student: <span class="white-text">@{{studentDetail.firstname}}&nbsp;&nbsp;@{{studentDetail.middlename[0]}}.&nbsp;&nbsp;@{{studentDetail.lastname}}</span></p>
                                <p>Subject: <span class="white-text">@{{subject_slug}}</span></p>
                                <hr>
                            </strong>
                        </small>
                    </header>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div ng-repeat="detail in examDetail">
                    <header ng-bind="detail.title"></header>
                    <br>
                    <p>@{{detail.question}}</p>
                    <p>@{{detail.choice_a}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@{{detail.choice_b}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@{{detail.choice_c}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@{{detail.choice_d}}</p>
                    <div class="input-field s6">
                        <label for="answers">Answer</label>
                        <input type="text" name="answers" id="answers" ng-model="answers" class="validate">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="mobileSubmitExam()">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have already test the my api in POSTMAN and it work (using the format below).

```
answers = {"1": "testing", "2": "testing2"}
student_id = some id
subject_slug = some-subject
subject_id = some id
```

but i actually used it my backend get null espeacially the tempAnswer. i think the bug is in my angular, is there someone could give some idea or solution much better ^_^. Hoping for your response guys, i am totally new to angular, but i am learning it eagerly.

Comment: I think you should watch real posted data with network traces of developper tools in Chrome or FF (F12 to open, then Network tab). This will help you see if there is a mistake client-side or server-side (an unexpected JSON level for example).

Comment: i already did that, i always opened my developers tool when i am coding.  internal error.

Comment: if you already inspected data being sent within the actual request then problem is server side

Comment: sir the server side is ok like i said i tested it in POSTMAN, i think it in my frontend,

Comment: @MichaelMendoza Since you tested the server side, the logical next step would be to inspect the request that your client is sending, and see if it matches what you did in POSTMAN.

Comment: precisely. That is my problem, can you take a look in my code the angular code? and see what i am lacking?

Comment: var submitInfo = {
            'answers': $scope.answers;
            'student_id': $scope.studentDetail.id,
            'subject_slug': $scope.subject_slug,
            'subject_id': subject_id
        };   i think this area i got bugged.

Comment: I think the most useful in your case to debug is really to see what is produced. You can use Wireshark as well if your server is not localhost (or you are not on Windows).

Comment: You could also do a "console.log(submitInfo)" before the $http.post, and then copy/paste displayed JSON into your server to test it.

Comment: i did that, $scope answers is agot bugged. supposively the format should be like this {"id", answer} before it decoded from JSON. the problem is how can i get all question id (id) and the answers i don't have the hook. T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have already debug this bug on my app. if somebody has the same problem maybe it could help, i have couple change both view and the model(angular side) here it is.

in angular side i have created empty object which will be the container of answer as well for the id of each question.

```
$cope.answers={}; // declare globally.

$scope.mobileSubmitExam = function() {

        var result = $window.confirm('Are you sure to submit?');
        var submitInfo = {
            'answers': JSON.stringify($scope.answers),
            'student_id': $scope.studentDetail.id,
            'subject_slug': $scope.subject_slug,
            'subject_id': subject_id
        };
        console.log(submitInfo);
        if(result == true) {

            $http.post(BASE_URL + 'mobile/examination/submit', submitInfo)
                .success(function(response) {
                    $scope.answers = '';
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .error(function() {
                    $window.confirm('Error on submitting the examination!');
                })
        }
    };
```

and in the view.

```
<input type="text" name="answers" id="answers" ng-model="answers[detail.id]" class="validate"> // after.

<input type="text" name="answers" id="answers" ng-model="answers" class="validate"> // before.
```

thats it.. thank you for all the comments and reactions i really really appreciated it..

Comment: Ok you added "console.log" at a right place. Now, when you watch console output (F12 developper tools),  what do you see when you submit ? (The Json).